# Rails "no matching POST" for new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm re-writing this post as I just tried to re-do the work but still can't figure out what's going on.

in my routes.rb, I have

```
resources :events
```

I moved the Events Controller and the Events Views outside the project so save the work, then re-created the Events controller.

```
Rails g controller Events new create edit update destroy index show
```

Returned an error about the EventsHelper already existing, so removed that as well and started the generator again.

so since I'm trying to get the create to work, I only defined the new and the create actions so far in the Controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @event = Event.new
    
    if current_user&.admin_role?
        render layout: "admin/base"
    end
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title,
                                    :event_status,
                                    :registration_required,
                                    :cover_img, 
                                    :cover_img_alt,
                                    :description, 
                                    :start, 
                                    :end, 
                                    :cost, 
                                    :category, 
                                    :zoom_room, 
                                    :access_room, 
                                    :registration_url,
                                    :registration_full,
                                    learning_objectives_attributes: [:id, :objective, :_destroy],
                                    ceus_attributes: [:id, :ceu_type, :ceu_amount, :_destroy],
                                    rooms_attributes: [:id, :name, :url, :_destroy, 
                                      accomodations_attributes: [:id, :accomodation, :_destroy]],
                                    accomodations_attributes: [:id, :accomodation, :_destroy],
                                    bios_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :img_url, :img_description, :bio, :bio_type, :_destroy])
    end
    
    def user_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :password, :identify_as, 
        events_attributs: [:id, :include_ceu])
    end
end
```

Here's what I have for the new.html.haml

```
.container.p-4
    .row
        .col-md-9
            %h1 Create New Event
            = render 'events/forms/new/form'
```

_form.html.haml

```
= form_with url: new_event_path, method: "post" do |f|
  
  = render 'events/forms/parts/errors'
  = render 'events/forms/parts/basic_info', f: f
  .d-grid.gap-2.d-md-block.p-4.bg-light
    = f.submit "Create Event", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"
    = link_to 'Cancel', events_path, class: "btn btn-secondary btn-lg", role: "button"
```

forms/parts/_errors.html.haml

```
- if @event.errors.any?
  .alert.alert-warning.border.border-dark{role: "alert"}
    %h2 #{pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error")} prevented us from processing the form:
    %ul
      - event.errors.each do |error|
        %li= error.full_message
```

forms/parts/_basic.html.haml

```
.form-floating.mb-4
  = f.text_field :title, class: "form-control border border-dark", placeholder: "Event Title"
  = f.label :title, "Event Title"
  
.row
  .col-md-6.mb-4
    .form-floating
      = f.url_field :cover_img, class: "form-control border border-dark", placeholder: "Cover Image URL"
      = f.label :cover_img, "Cover Image URL"
      
  .col-md-6.mb-4
    .form-floating
      = f.text_field :cover_img_alt, class: "form-control border border-dark", placeholder: "Description of the cover image"
      = f.label :cover_img_alt, "Description of the cover image"
      
.row
  .col-md-6.mb-4
    .form-floating
      = f.datetime_field :start, placeholder: "Start Date and Time", class: "form-control border border-dark"
      = f.label :start, "Start Date and Time"
      
  .col-md-6.mb-4
    .form-floating
      = f.datetime_field :end, placeholder: "End Date and Time", class: "form-control border border-dark"
      = f.label :end, "End Date and Time"
      
.row
  .col-md-6.mb-4
    .form-floating
      = f.text_field :category, class: "form-control border border-dark", placeholder: "Category"
      = f.label :category, "Category"
    
.form-group
  = f.label :registration_url, "Registration URL"
  = f.url_field :registration_url, class: "form-control"
.form-group.mb-4
  = f.label :registration_full, "Registration is Full"
  = f.check_box :registration_full, class: "form-check"
.form-group.mb-4
  = f.label :registration_required, "Registration required"
  = f.check_box :registration_required, class: "form-check"
  
.form-group.mb-4
  = f.label :description, "Description"
  = f.text_area :description, class: "form-control"
```

When I hit create, I get this error:
No route matches [POST] "/events/new"

And running rails routes gives me this segment

```
rails routes | grep "events"
                              events_new GET    /events/new(.:format)                                                                             events#new
                           events_create GET    /events/create(.:format)                                                                          events#create
                             events_edit GET    /events/edit(.:format)                                                                            events#edit
                           events_update GET    /events/update(.:format)                                                                          events#update
                          events_destroy GET    /events/destroy(.:format)                                                                         events#destroy
                            events_index GET    /events/index(.:format)                                                                           events#index
                             events_show GET    /events/show(.:format)                                                                            events#show
                 create_checkout_session POST   /create-checkout-session(.:format)                                                                events#create_checkout_session
                                 success GET    /success(.:format)                                                                                events#success
                                  events GET    /events(.:format)                                                                                 events#index
                                         POST   /events(.:format)                                                                                 events#create
                               new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                                                                             events#new
                              edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                        events#edit
                                   event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                                                                             events#show
                                         PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                                                                             events#update
                                         PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                                                                             events#update
                                         DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                                                                             events#destroy
```

I see here is a POST but it doesn't have a path, and it's for the #create action, but for some reason it's not working.  Any suggestions?  My other controllers work fine though.

Answer (score 1):

In your `_forms.html.haml` file why your url is `new_event_path`, shouldn't it be a post request to `events_path`.

So your file should something like this:

```
= form_with url: events_path, method: "post" do |f|
  
  = render 'events/forms/parts/errors'
  = render 'events/forms/parts/basic_info', f: f
  .d-grid.gap-2.d-md-block.p-4.bg-light
    = f.submit "Create Event", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"
    = link_to 'Cancel', events_path, class: "btn btn-secondary btn-lg", role: "button"
```

Comment: This solved the issue of routing, but now I have : "param is missing or the value is empty: event".

Comment: @PatrickVellia 
Problem lies here I presume in your controller.
```
def user_params
      params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :password, :identify_as, 
        events_attributs: [:id, :include_ceu])
end
```
You are looking for params `event` but it is not event there. Removing the event should do the work. I hope it helps.